# Unable to send email in go smtp library with gmail

Tags: email, go, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send email through golang's smtp library using my gamil account.

It was working fine when I try to send emails a few days ago.

But suddenly today, I am not able to send email and the error shown is:

535 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials h3sm2390100pji.16 - gsmtp

I'm sure that it succeed in signing into gmail because, 1. the username and password are correct, 2. When I push my code to the server and try to send the email again, my gmail account receive a "Critical Security Alert" email, saying that I have less secure access on, and I have selected that I have recognized the activity.

This shows that I have indeed able to login to gmail through my golang program, yet it was unable to send any email.

I have already turned on allow less secure access and I also have tried this https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha, and my password for gmail is "upper case letter + lower case letter + special symbols + numbers"

I have been stuck in this since I have tried all possible solution on the internet and still could not able to send email again using the golang program.

And the port I was using is 587.
By changing it to 465, it gives an error of EOF instead.

Comment: First: SMTP or SMTPS? And port 5**8**7 is quite distinct to 465. The former provides TLS only, whereas the latter provides SSL only.

Comment: Sorry, typo, it should be 587. I think I'm using SMTP, not sure which one gmail supports